# Inherited ImageButton Background Padding

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view, android-background

I'm creating a simple [custom view](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html). My view inherits from [AppCompatImageButton](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatImageButton.html) with the goal of drawing some simple geometric shapes for my custom button and animating them.

If my XML view contains:

```
android:background="@color/transparent"
```

My view draws correctly inside a vertical LinearLayout, even though the android:background seems to otherwise do nothing. However, if I leave out android:background, the top and bottom displays an additional unwanted gap between the custom views.

The documentation says these two are "Related":

[View.setBackgroundResource(int resid)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundResource(int))

[android:background](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:background)

I've tried calling setBackgroundResource(R.color.transparent) in my Java initialization code, thinking this would do the same thing as XML android:background, but the unwanted padding won't go away. Here's a screenshot that shows the view without the android:background.

[image]

With android:background, the image fills the entire height not leaving the gap at the top and bottom.

How can I get my custom view to fill the entire drawing area without forcing an artificial android:background into the XML? The solution will also need to work if the programmer creates the custom view in Java without XML.

Thx.

Comment: Please attach screenshots

Comment: @BabulPatel, does this help?

Comment: setBackgroundResource(getResources().getColor(R.color.dark_blue))--------------try this.

Comment: @BabuPatel... That doesn't compile, but I've tried similar. setBackgroundResource(R.color.transparent); as already mentioned in my post. No effect.

Comment: I can also inherit from AppCompatImageView to remove the unwanted gap. I'm not super happy with this as a solution as I'd like the user to click the buttons and have the programmer handle the clicks without extra coding on my part. Without a better suggestion, I'll move forward with this option.